# 'STRU' namespace in the Windows Internals API?

Tags: windows

In `w3wp.exe`, `STRU` namespace is used. Where is the `STRU` namespace documented? With functions like `STRU::QuerySizeCCH()`, `STRU::Resize()`?

Comment: Where did you see them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those functions are exported by IISUTIL.DLL. That is not a core Windows library, and thus wouldn't be documented in any "Windows Internals" references.

Comment: Where did you find the IISUTIL.DLL reference?

Comment: In w3wp.exe's Import Table.

Comment: How do you get to this 'Import Table' When I hit Control+Insert in IDA PRO nothing happens.

Comment: View --> Open subviews --> Imports (https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1416.shtml)

Comment: Found it. Thank you very much! Any clue why this is called QuerySizeCCH: int __thiscall STRU::QuerySizeCCH(int this)
{
  return *(_DWORD *)(this + 36) >> 1;
}

Comment: @Craln: ask a new question instead of expanding the current one in the comments. Microsoft often uses abbreviations `Cch` to denote "count of characters" and `Cb` to denote "count of bytes". IIS, like most Microsoft products, uses 16-bit characters, known as `WCHAR` or `wchar_t`. Seems that some buffer's *size in bytes* is stored at `this+36`, and this function takes it and divides it by two to convert it to *size in characters*.